# How to Save a Leaflet Map?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have a webpage with a Leaflet Map, I can add markers,filter markers and so on. My question is that how can I save it?

1.Load the Map
2.Add some Markers on the Map
3.(Optional) Filter the Markers on the Map
4.Save the map together with the Markers that put on the map in a database(any possible storage)
5.Opening the map in the browser and view same as what i just saved.

Ive search everything but its too hard to do it any possible suggestions?, TYIA

Comment: You can store the (current) bounding box of the map and the coordinates of the markers in the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I hope you can give sample illustrations because I dont know how to start this, If you just want.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on backend you are using.

For Database you can use Postgresql with PostGIS. You create table with geometry or geography column and save marker latlng there. In other columns you saves additional data that define marker (id, description, whatever).

You can also save current marker layer as geojson file. And load it on opening map.

But you need to write some backend that takes in markers data or geojson and do something with it server side.

You can also take a look at Leaflet.Storage (and django-leaflet-storage as an backend)

Comment: This is my first time doing this kind of program sir mapping system and the best way i think for database is mysql with a table fields of float and text. is that enough sir? i thought its like vb.net with mysql database but its not. Im still looking forward to have a sample codes or tutorial from you but now i just wanna say thank you for your concern. you can see my sample code here sir. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872208/error-in-marker-with-database