# Error in Marker with Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

My goal here is that i want to show a default marker in map of my website.
the code below shows how to view a default marker in a given lat/lng

```
function getInfo() { 
        $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
            var name = data[i].name; 
            var marker = new L.Marker(location); 
            marker.bindPopup("<div style='text-align: center; margin- 
left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>"+ title +"</div>", {maxWidth: 
'200'}); 
            users.addLayer(marker); 
          } 
        }).complete(function() { 
          if (firstLoad == true) { 
            map.fitBounds(users.getBounds()); 
            firstLoad = false; 
          }; 
        }); 
      }
```

the second below is for database.

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poi', 'root', ''); 
$sql = "SELECT id,lat, lng FROM users;"; 

$rs = $db->query($sql); 
if (!$rs) { 
    echo "An SQL error occured.\n"; 
    exit; 
} 

$rows = array(); 
while($r = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $rows[] = $r; 
} 
print json_encode($rows); 
$db = NULL; 
?>
```

my goal here is that when i load my website with map a default marker will show in a place given the lat/lng from database but when i load it nothing happens whats wrong with my code? any help? ty

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: sir where i will put your code? i mean where i will place this. sorry this is my first time

Comment: Under `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poi', 'root', '');` should there be a DB related error.

Comment: sir what is the use of this? because when i refresh my browser nothing happens

Comment: i follow what you said bit nothing happens

Comment: there's no error happens sir

Comment: I don't know what else it could be then, sorry.

Comment: its okay sir, i just wanna ask if you have link or tutorial that is related to my problem? you know, how to save marker to database and display it in map. im using leaflet

Comment: That I couldn't say, I never use that type of code myself.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Where is your declaration to `$users`? 2. Are you sure `$rows[]` isn't empty? Or in other words, what's the output of `print json_encode($rows); `?

Comment: honestly sir i did not actually understand what you said because this my first time encountering leaflet map. my answer in your 1st question is $users is the table name. 2nd answer is that my database has a data lat/long/marker name/id and the output must be a default leaflet marker in a map. :(